Particle effect on Instances
I am trying to make a particle effect on the flowers (instantiated using geometry nodes) on the skull mesh:

I tried doing it in geometry nodes, but the random points distributed on the flowers do not show up in the simulation zone at all.
Here are the points on the flowers:

But not in simulation zone:

My question is if this is the right way to add partciles, as adding the particles to the original flowers object doesn't work anyway?
Geometry nodes:



I suspect it's a bug. What Blender version are you using? Here's my view in B4.1.1 https://i.imgur.com/DKMMwtB.png Sorry I see now you also use 4.1.1...

@MarkusvonBroady The particles appear if they are instantiated and then connected to the viewer node. If you restart from the first frame, they disappear and don't appear throughout the animation.

You set the scale to 0 at the beginning so the faces have no area so no points are spawned on them.
